# Servidor permita trabajar de forma concurrente con varios clientes

Tags: java

He creado la clase servidor, pero no soy capaz de hacer que los clientes trabajen de forma concurrente con varios clientes, he visto tutoriales y no soy capaz de modificar mi código para que esto pueda hacerse.

Me pueden ayudar por favor? Muchas gracias de atemano, os dejo por aquí mi código.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int nSecreto = generar_nSecreto();
        int nJugador = 0;
        boolean adivinado = false;

        System.out.println("Número secreto generado al azar en el servidor: " + nSecreto);

        ServerSocket sServidor = null;
        Socket sCliente = null;

        System.out.println("Servidor OK...\n Esperando jugadores...");

        try {

            sServidor = new ServerSocket(1500);
            sCliente = sServidor.accept();
            System.out.println("Se ha conectado en el servidor");

            DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sCliente.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream salida = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(sCliente.getOutputStream()));

            while (true) {
                if (!adivinado) {
                    nJugador = entrada.readInt();

                    if (nJugador == nSecreto) {
                        adivinado = true;
                        salida.writeBoolean(true);
                    } else if (nJugador > nSecreto) {
                        salida.writeBoolean(false);
                        salida.writeUTF("\n[INCORRECTO]: El número es menor que " + nJugador + "\n");
                    } else if (nJugador < nSecreto) {
                        salida.writeBoolean(false);
                        salida.writeUTF("\n[INCORRECTO]: El número es mayor que " + nJugador + "\n");
                    }
                } else if (adivinado) {
                    salida.writeUTF("\nHas acertado el número secreto [ " + nJugador + " ] ¡Enorabuena!\n");
                } else {
                    sServidor.close();
                    sCliente.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("\nError al intentar escuchar por el puerto 1500 o la conexión con el jugador\n");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static int generar_nSecreto() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 150 + 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un par de cosas que no me quedan claras respecto a cómo se han de comportar los clientes y el servidor en caso de fallar y acertar las respuestas, pero en principio, lo que debes hacer es que cada cliente se ejecute en un Thread separado para evitar que el servidor se quede bloqueado. El código sería algo como esto:

```
private static class Jugador extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private int nSecreto;
    private boolean adivinado = false;

    public Jugador(Socket socket, int nSecreto) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.nSecreto = nSecreto;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream salida = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));

            int nJugador = entrada.readInt();

            if (!adivinado) {
                if (nJugador == nSecreto) {
                    adivinado = true;
                    salida.writeBoolean(true);
                } else if (nJugador > nSecreto) {
                    salida.writeBoolean(false);
                    salida.writeUTF("\n[INCORRECTO]: El número es menor que " + nJugador + "\n");
                } else if (nJugador < nSecreto) {
                    salida.writeBoolean(false);
                    salida.writeUTF("\n[INCORRECTO]: El número es mayor que " + nJugador + "\n");
                }
            } else if (adivinado) {
                salida.writeUTF("\nHas acertado el número secreto [ " + nJugador + " ] ¡Enorabuena!\n");
            } else {
                //Este juego de if/else if/else es lo que no entiendo, pero no importa de cara a lo que estás preguntando
                //socket.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log de excepcion
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int nSecreto = generar_nSecreto();

    System.out.println("Número secreto generado al azar en el servidor: " + nSecreto);

    ServerSocket sServidor = null;

    System.out.println("Servidor OK...\n Esperando jugadores...");

    try {

        sServidor = new ServerSocket(1500);
        System.out.println("Se ha conectado en el servidor");

        while (true) {
            Jugador tJugador = new Jugador(sServidor.accept(), nSecreto);
            tJugador.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("\nError al intentar escuchar por el puerto 1500 o la conexión con el jugador\n");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda Ivan Clavijos, estoy aprendiendo actualmente a como programar con socket en Java , y la verdad que cualquier ayuda me vale oro en paño. Ahora quiero hacer un ejemplo sencillo de que una vez iniciada sesión a través de un nombre de usuario y contraseña específico y el sistema permita Ver el contenido del directorio actual, mostrar el contenido de un determinado archivo y salir. Donde podría ver un ejemplo de como se pueden poner nombres y contraseñas a un socket antes de inciar sesion el cliente? o me podría explicar? Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hola Juan. Hasta donde yo sé, no hay nada para "securizar" un socket salvo que hagas tú tu propia implementación (y tendrás que empezar a liarte con certificados y similares). Echa un vistazo a esto, por ejemplo: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/SSLClientSession.htm

Comment: Ah, y si te ha servido mi respuesta, sería de agradecer que la marcases como válida, gracias :)

Comment: Ya le he dado a validar jejeje espero que te ayude. Lo que me refería es a lo siguiente. Es un ejercicio de clase y tengo que hacerlo así.  A partir del ejercicio anterior crea un servidor que una vez iniciada sesión a través de un nombre de usuario y contraseña específico (por ejemplo javier / secreta) el sistema permita Ver el contenido del directorio actual, mostrar el contenido de un determinado archivo y salir.

Para realizar el ejercicio primero debes crear un diagrama de estados que muestre el funcionamiento del servidor.

Comment: En ese caso, en el hilo que abres para cada cliente debes leer dos cadenas, validar que sean usuario/contraseña correctos y, de ser así, pasar a una fase en que, mediante opciones (0 ver directorio, 1 <nombre archivo> ver archivo, 9 salir, por ejemplo) el usuario indique qué quiere hacer.